# Jquery .click() gives me "stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, jquery

What in my code gives me this error?

> jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded

**HTML**

```
<form id="addPhotoForm">
    <img class="pull-right" src="" width="100px" height="140px"/>
    <input type="file" id="addPhotoInput" name="addPhotoInput" style="display: none;"/> 
</form>
```

**JS**

```
//On click Photo
$('#addPhotoForm').on('click', function(){
    //Check if usrname exist
    var usrname = $('#usrname').val();
    if(usrname){
        $('#addPhotoInput').trigger('click');
    }
    else{
        alert("!");
    }
})
```

How can i solve this error?
I'm trying to open the file dialog when clicking on the form.

**UPDATE**
I tried:

```
$('#addPhotoInput').click();
```

Comment: Infinite loop... Click handler is being called again and again inside itself...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? When clicking the elements within the form or submitting the form?

Comment: @Rayon How come? and how can i stop it?

Comment: @Mjukis, `$('#addPhotoInput').trigger('click');` will call it..To prevent it, _Do not `trigger` it!_

Comment: Look at it? You say on 'Click' trigger 'Click' and then it keeps on going on and on and on... How does that not make sense to you?

Comment: @wmash I'm trying to open the file dialog whenever i click the form.

Comment: @Mjukis Then call native DOM click method instead: `$('#addPhotoInput')[0].click();`

Comment: @A.Wolff Wolf I like your answear. Please add it and i will choose it. Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To avoid any click event handler bound using jQuery to get fired, and still keep event propagation (useful if any delegate click event is bound too), you could call native DOM `click()` method instead:

```
$('#addPhotoInput')[0].click();
```

Or:

```
$('#addPhotoInput').get(0).click();
```

Which are the same as:

```
document.getElementById('addPhotoInput').click();
```

Answer (score 5):

You have attached `click event` to form itself.So, when `any form element` is get clicked,due `event bubbling` it get `captured` by form again.So,It will call `click event` on form again.And the same process is repeated again and again

You can prevent [event propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('#addPhotoForm').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

   // rest of the code goes here
})
```

EDIT : 
You should attache event handler to other element inside form which is visible to end-user and not to form

Comment: The issue is about children click event propagation, not on the parent level. `$('#addPhotoForm')` should be `$('#addPhotoInput')`

Comment: when children get clicked it is get bubbled to parent in DOM tree

Comment: But you are stopping click event propagation at `#addPhotoForm` level

Comment: I can see it now. Thank you for great explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can use namespace for click events

```
$('#addPhotoInput').on('click.input',function(){
    // do something
});

//On click Photo
$('#addPhotoForm').on('click.form', function(){
    //Check if usrname exist
    var usrname = $('#usrname').val();
    if(usrname){
        $('#addPhotoInput').trigger('click.input');
    }
    else{
        alert("!");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was listening for a mouse event and emitted a corresponding new event, which caused a loop. I found that checking [Event # isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) is helpful here, because we can distinguish between "real" and "artifical" events:

```js
listen(myElement, ['mousedown'], event => {
    // Check if this is a "real" event, or our own (avoid endless loop)
    if (event.isTrusted) {
        const newEvent = new MouseEvent(event.type, event);
        myOtherElement.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
        newEvent.stopPropagation();

    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is seem to be a loop

```
//On click Photo
$('#addPhotoForm').on('click', function(){
    //Check if usrname exist
    var usrname = $('#usrname').val();
    if(usrname){
        $('#addPhotoInput').trigger('click');
    }
    else{
        alert("!");
    }
})
```

When you click on the form, the event listener triggers click event on the input inside the form. And the click event on the input bubbles click event up to the DOM tree. The click event listener on the form gets triggered again.

You need to prevent from bubbling the click event when clicking the input

```
$('#addPhotoInput').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   // do some action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop `#addPhotoInput`'s click event from bubbling up.

```
$('#addPhotoInput').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    // your code
}
```

When you click on a child element, the parent element receives a click as well.

`e.stopPropagation()` prevents that behaviour.

In your case, clicking `#addPhotoInput` meant clicking `#addPhotoForm` as well, because they were nested. Therefore, the form's event handler was called, which once again triggered the input handler, repeating the process recursively and infinitely.

This is why you received that particular error message.